# Input from two alternative sources in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, input

I'm trying to implement a speech recognition system to call commands (CMD module). As the SR libraries don't recognize everything, I'd like to leave an open door to be able to call certain commands by a text input as well. What I don't know if is possible is to wait for inputs from different sources, something like this:

```
def get_input():
    my_input = input('> ') or audio_input()
    return my_input
```

Obviously, if the source is an audio, it has to be processed to get the text, so I'd also like to have a flag to recognize what type did the user send, either text or audio.

Is there a way to do something like this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try it? If you hit Enter without typing anything else the input will be `''`, which is false-y, and the `audio_input` function will be called instead. Is that *not* the behaviour you want?

Comment: In fact, I tried it, and it's kinda similar to what I want, but avoiding to press enter everytime I want to input a voice command. As @user1620443 wrote, I guess I'll need to try the multithreading module. Thanks very much though for the comment

Comment: Consider building a simple Tkinter GUI to input the text command in a text entry field, instead of the console. The GUI will run in the background and when the user enters something it can call whatever callback you specify. Other GUI toolkits will work as well, but Tkinter ships with Python as standard.

Answer (score 1):

As johnsharpe wrote in the comment, the behaviour on your code seems fine. If you want to check for the two inputs *at the same time* and work on the first that comes out, you'll need some sort of multithreading, which complicates a little the issue. You could start checking out the python multithreading package.

As far as recognition of the input type, I imagine textual input will be a string, while the audio some other kind of object. Once you collect your input you could just check the kind of object by using `isinstance`.

Comment: I guess it'll be the way to achieve this, but I'm running out of time today to try it, so I'll try it ASAP and leave a comment with the results. Thanks very much for the answer